# How do I move a method to a separate file in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    myMethod () { /**/ }
}
```

But I want to move myMethod to a separate file. I have tried making a new file,

myMethod.js:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = () => { /**/ }
```

and importing it on my main file like this:

```
import './myMethod.js';
```

but I get the error: `ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined`

Changing the import statement or trying to add an export line to myMethod.js makes no difference. It just seems it cant find MyClass.

This seems like a pretty common issue so I don't understand what I'm supposed to do or why I can't find anything about it on google. Splitting my class into multiple files is the reason I want to use webpack.

Comment: But why do you want split a single method?

Comment: So I don't have a single file that's thousands of lines long, makes much more sense to put methods in their own files

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack's code split to create a separate chunk, the only down side if that this method most be an async one.

```js
// MyClass.js

class MyClass {

}

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = async (...args) => {
   const { myMethod } = await import('./myMethod');

   return myMethod.apply(MyClass.prototype, args);
}
```

```js
// myMethod.js

export const myMethod = function myMethod() {
  ...
}
```